# How to use third party library in Python?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I have recently started working with Python so I installed `PyCharm community edition version` in my windows 7 laptop and I am able to run few Python program successfully.

This is second day with Python so I am enjoying a lot.

Now I need to work with `kazoo` zookeeper library.. Until now, I was working with `kazoo` library through command prompt using cygwin and it was working fine..

Now I am thinking to use kazoo library directly with `PyCharm` just like if you need to use any other library in java, you can add those into maven dependency or into build path.

Is there any similar thing to do it PyCharm or in Python?

This is the kazoo library link - http://kazoo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

in which they have mentioned how to install kazoo but I am not sure how to make that work in my `PyCharm`.

Can anyone provide me step by step guidance on how to use kazoo in PyCharm IDE (how to install it properly so that I can start using it) considering the fact, I don't know much about Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a package manager for your installation of python. The recommended one is `PIP`. Here's how you can install it from Terminal or Command Prompt:

http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

Once that's installed, you can install your `kazoo` library with the instructions they provided you.

Comment: PyCharm just uses some installation of Python, somewhere on your system. PIP install new packages into that installation. That's about as much integration as you're going to get.